# Should I frame behind a basement shower above the shorty foundation?

Tags: framing

I have an existing half concrete wall in the basement where I intend to frame over the concrete in the bedroom portion of the lower level and have a ledge. It's a waist high concrete wall that comes out a couple inches, then waist-up drywall, again in a couple inches -- it's not a flat wall in other words.

However, in the bathroom portion there will be a shower that goes up against that wall.  Do I just frame up to the ceiling for the purposes of attaching the shower to the wall?

Comment: It is hard to visualize what your project is.  Please post some pics of the area .

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, for a prefabricated shower stall, you would just frame to the ceiling beside it.

If your new wall is longer than 10 ft, which seems unlikely in a bathroom, then technically you should have vertically oriented fire blocking in the upper part where there's a gap between your new framing and the existing wall. Stuffed full of mineral wool insulation batts or mineral fiber insulation batts qualifies as fireblocking under [2021 IBC 718.2.1.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IBC2021P2/chapter-7-fire-and-smoke-protection-features#IBC2021P2_Ch07_Sec718.2.1.1). Solid wood and drywall also work.